# Can we put text on a specific page on prawn pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am using Prawn to generate pdf in rails.
I am trying to find a way to go to a specific page and write something on it.

Here is what I try to do, I already defined `pdf` and `@page_count`

```
(@page_count - 1).times do
    pdf.start_new_page
end
```

Then I tried to go to certain page and write something, for instance:

```
pdf.page(1)  #will go to page No.1, 
pdf.text 'Hi'
```

I checked on prawn site but it seems like they do not have this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try to the following:

```
pdf.go_to_page(1)
pdf.text 'Hi'
```

*You can get total pages via* `pdf.page_count`

Comment: This is the documentation site: 
[Class: Prawn::Document](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/Prawn/Document.html#go_to_page-instance_method)